# The meaning of "find up and down the church"

Tags: meaning

> And, as the singing began, all the people who were in the pews within
>   the wall came out of them and streamed through the archway into the
>   nave. **They took what places they could find up and down the
>   church,** and the rest of the congregation looked at them in
>   amazement.

This is from "The Great Return" by Arthur Macken.
http://www.gutenberg.org/files/35611/35611-h/35611-h.htm

I don't undestand the meaning of the sentence below.
They took what places they could find up and down the church,

I am glad if someone would kindly teach me.

Answer (score 2):

"places they could find" means the seats that were available, implying that most of the seats were taken so that people needed to search a bit to find an available one.

"up and down the church" means in all parts of the church, not just in the front or just in the back.